# Are array elements also passed by value or by reference?

Tags: c

I know that arrays are passed by reference in a function call, but what if you only pass an array element, e.g. `func(ar[0])`. Does `arg[0]` get passed by value or by reference?

Comment: depends whether it is an array or not.  A larger code sample would help

Comment: Arrays are not passed by reference. An array expression decays to a pointer to its first element, though, which is customarily passed to functions. Everything in C is passed by value.

Comment: @KerrekSB Arrays are passed by reference in C. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) for definition of "pass by reference".  A pointer fits the definition of [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are not passed by reference, they *decay* as pointers when used as function arguments or in a expression, except as an operand to the `sizeof` operator.  Hence a function receives a pointer to the first element of the array, regardless of how the argument is defined in the function prototype, as a pointer or an array.

If you pass an array element, it is passed by value, unless this array element is an array itself, in which case a pointer to the first element is passed.

Comment: @AndrésRivero: can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your array type is will get passed rather than a pointer to that element.

```
int a[2];
a[0] =5;
a[1] =6;

func1( a[0] ); // passes int to func1
func2( &a[1] ); // passes pointer to int 

func1( int z )...
func2( int * z )...
```